# problems passing variable to search method

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm working doing a search and invoking the search from a web submit form. I can't seem to get the variable to pass into the argument from the search box.

This is for an instagram search app.  I'm trying to retrieve a particular users feed:

This is the call to get the users feed:

```
$result = $instagram->searchUser($id);
```

This calls this function:

```
public function searchUser($name, $limit = 0) {
    return $this->_makeCall('users/search', false, array('q' => $name, 'count' => $limit));
}
```

My issue is getting that '$id' passed into this.  This is what I have in the html thus far, and I realize i may be way off here, but im (obviously) new at this.

```
  <form id="sform" method="post">
    <fieldset>

        <input id="s" type="text" />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="id" />

        <div id="searchInContainer">
            <input type="radio" name="check" value="site" id="id" checked />
           >

        </div>



    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: first I will assume your input `id="s"` is your search input? change or add `name="s"` then get s from `$id= $_POST['s'];` as the POST variable uses the name attribute and not the ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some inconsistencies in your code. Firstly, your original call to `searchUser()` passes in a variable named `$id`, then your **definition** of that function has a variable named `$name` - there's nothing wrong with this technically, but it's easy to mix up your arguments when they are named differently and generically like that.

Your problem is your form, you have more than one ID assigned to elements, which is against the HTML spec. You also need to give the textbox a **name** attribute, otherwise no data will get posted to your form.

Next, you need to define an action for the form tag to tell the browser where to direct the post location - this is your PHP file that makes the API call. Let's say its `myfile.php`, try a form like this:

```
<form id="sform" action="myfile.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input name="search" id="search" type="text" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButtom" />
        <div id="searchInContainer">
            <input type="radio" name="check" value="site" id="yourCheckbox" checked />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Once your HTML is sorted out, you simply need to get the variable in PHP and pass it to your API:

```
$id = $_POST['search'];
$result = $instagram->searchUser($id);
```

I'd suggest with that syntax above for some basic SQL injection vulnerabilities, if you're expecting a number to be sent in, use: `$id = (int) $_POST['search'];` to force the variable to be an integer (stripping out malicious characters etc).

Comment: Thanks for the useful reply.  Two questions come after reading this.. First.. i want this search page to contain this code:  '$id = $_POST['search'];
$result = $instagram->searchUser($id);'  So no redirect if possible.

Comment: update: Thanks for the useful reply.  A question after reading this..  i want this search page to contain this code:  '$id = $_POST['search'];
$result = $instagram->searchUser($id);'  So no redirect if possible.  The "SearchUser" fucntion is in another file with most of the methods. but i want each page to do its own thing.. so this page will just search users. and so on

Comment: OK, you'll need to change the form action to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to post to itself, and check for the existence of the posted data before processing it: `if(isset($_POST['search'])) { /* ... do your stuff */ }`

Comment: This is my full code [posted here.](https://gist.github.com/TommyVon/9924209) Do I put the if/then at the top with the variable or around the search form?

Comment: Put the entire results container, and the PHP that processes the search through Instagram API inside if statement like above.

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is the `$_POST` superglobal. When you submit your form, the content of each field is put into a `$_POST` variable which is accessible by the script.

```
<form id="sform" method="post" action="searchUser.php">
    <fieldset>
        <input id="s" name="userid" type="text" />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="id" />

        <div id="searchInContainer">
            <input type="radio" name="check" value="site" checked />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

`searchUser.php` will get called when the user submits that form, and will have the variable `$_POST['userid']` which contains the content of the text field. That means:

```
$result = $instagram->searchUser($_POST['userid']);
```

would then work! `$_POST['check']` is also available at that point, and you can do `var_dump($_POST)` to see what is coming in from your form if you need to debug!

I would **strongly** suggest doing some data validation on any user-submitted data field, however! Don't assume what is in a `$_POST` variable is safe!

You can take a look at the [PHP Documentation](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) to learn some more! `$_POST` is one of a family of superglobals that will help you out!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Already alot of help.  Is there anyway to make this code all live in "searchUser.php" with no redirect?  The "SearchUser" method is in a file with all the code to do that. I'd just like to have one page for each search i'm conducting. One page to search the users feed, one to search tags, one to search locations, etc.

Comment: Absolutely. Take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/paulflypay/9923873) I just threw together for you - hopefully it makes sense!

Comment: Ahh, excellent.  Take a look at what I have, as its different than what you have.. I'm still getting errors but i think its for different reasons. [link](https://gist.github.com/TommyVon/9924209)